# Python AttributeError: module 'runAnalytics' has no attribute 'run'

Tags: python, input, tkinter, python-3.5, attributeerror

I am trying to grab an input from my main.py file using tkinter and then use that input in runAnalytics.py

main.py

```
import runAnalytics
import tkinter
import os
import centerWindow

loadApplication = tkinter.Tk()
loadApplication.title("Stock Analytics")
loadApplication.geometry("1080x720")

label1 = tkinter.Label(loadApplication, text = "Ticker")
input1 = tkinter.Entry(loadApplication)

loadAnalytics = tkinter.Button(loadApplication, text = "Load Analytics", command = runAnalytics.run)

centerWindow.center(loadApplication)

loadAnalytics.pack()
label1.pack()
input1.pack()

loadApplication.mainloop()
```

runAnalytics.py

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
from main import input1
import tkinter
import os
import centerWindow


def run():
    ticker = input1
    loadAnalytics = tkinter.Tk()
    loadAnalytics.title("$" + ticker + " Data")
    loadAnalytics.geometry("1080x720")

    print ("Price per share: " + ticker.get_price())

    ticker.refresh()
    print ("Price per share: " + ticker.get_price())

    print("The dividend yield is: " + ticker.get_dividend_yield())

    print("The 52 week low is: " + ticker.get_year_low())
    print("The 52 week high is: " + ticker.get_year_high())
    print("The volume is: " + ticker.get_volume())

    print("The previous close was: " + ticker.get_prev_close())
    print("The previous open was: " + ticker.get_open())

    loadAnalytics.mainloop()
```

My error message reads as follows;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Python Projects\MarketData\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import runAnalytics
  File "C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Python Projects\MarketData\runAnalytics.py", line 2, in <module>
    from main import input1
  File "C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Python Projects\MarketData\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    loadAnalytics = tkinter.Button(loadApplication, text = "Load Analytics", command = runAnalytics.run)
AttributeError: module 'runAnalytics' has no attribute 'run'
```

Comment: Circular import problem. Restructure your code so you don't have two modules importing each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular import:

```
import runAnalytics
# ..
from main import input1
```

By the time `main` is being imported again, `runAnalytics` has not yet had a chance to execute the `def run():`.. section.

Resolve this by *removing* the `from main import input1` line, and pass that object in as an argument instead:

```
def run(input1):
```

passing this in from the `main.py` module when you call the function:

```
loadAnalytics = tkinter.Button(loadApplication, text = "Load Analytics", command = lambda: runAnalytics.run(input1))
```

Apart from the circular import, there is also the issue that whatever file you run as the main script in Python will be stored as the `__main__` module. Importing that same script again will lead to a *second* module being created, now under the name `main`, and any objects created in that module are distinct from those in `__main__`.

Next, you'll want to *remove* the `loadAnalytics.mainloop()` call from `run` as you should not start a new mainloop from an already running loop. You probably also want to create a new `TopLevel` window instead of creating another `Tk()` root. You'd have to pass in `loadApplication` to `run` too if you go this way.

Comment: This is much better than my answer as it covers both problems here.

Answer (score 1):

```
from runAnalytics import run

loadAnalytics = tkinter.Button(loadApplication, text="Load Analytics", command=run)
```

You don't want to start another `mainloop` of `tk`. Instead you should pass the `root` and create a toplevel window.

```
def run(root):
    ticker = input1
    parent = Toplevel(root)
    parent.title("$" + ticker + " Data")
    # the rest of your code
```

Comment: This still won't work, because of the circular import. The `from main import input1` line will run before `run` is defined in `runAnalytics` and `from runAnalytics import run` will still fail.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes you are correct, I was covering the other problem and I see your answer now covers both. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try adding () to the end of runAnalytics.run. You are currently telling it to look for a `run` attribute which it doesn't have instead of a function

```
loadAnalytics = tkinter.Button(loadApplication, text = "Load Analytics", command = runAnalytics.run())
```

Comment: That won't work as it will run as soon as the button is declared.

Comment: You can do this: `loadAnalytics = tkinter.Button(loadApplication, text = "Load Analytics", command = lambda: runAnalytics.run())`

Comment: Yes, your answer makes more sense

Comment: @double_j: that won't work either because `main.py` is the *main script* so is imported as `__main__`. `import main` will add another module object and `main.input1` and `__main__.input1` will be *two distinct objects*.